# when resource is not found in XAML

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

OK, I'm reading an article posted on CodeProject by Josh Smith and of course as going through it by adding XAML, resources, and etc. Again I see what I sometimes see in VS!

I have added "Resource" folder physically in directory and then imported it into project and its contents as well and even it runs fine but VS keep nagging (an error occurred while finding the source dictionary "Resources/RaceHorseDataTemplate.xaml)

```
<Grid.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- this line always has a red line underneath -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/RaceHorseDataTemplate.xaml" /> 
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
...
```

Am I missing something or is this a VS related issue? I am assuming should be something I have not done. any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.